# why the given code doesn't work for all test cases?Why it doesn't work when input is 7786?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
//code
int t,n,s;
cin>>t;//no. of test cases

for(int k=1;k<=t;k++)
{   cin>>n;s=0;//n:input,s:sum

        for(int i=1;i<=n*2;i++)
        {
            if(i%2==0)
               s=s+(i*i);
        }
    cout<<s<<endl;

}

return 0;
}
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**
Power of Pow | Even Number

Given a single integer N, your task is to find the sum of the square of first N even natural Numbers.

Examples:

Input : 3
Output : 56
2<sup>2</sup> + 4<sup>2</sup> + 6<sup>2</sup> = 56

Input : 8
Output : 816
2<sup>2</sup> + 4<sup>2</sup> + 6<sup>2</sup> + 8<sup>2</sup> + 10<sup>2</sup> + 12<sup>2</sup> + 14<sup>2</sup> + 16<sup>2</sup>

Input:
First line of the input contains an integer T, denoting the number of test cases. Then T test case follows. The only line of each test case contains an integer N.

Output:
For each test case output the required anser on a new line.
Constraints:

```
1<=T<=100
N<=104
```

Example:
Input:

```
3
2
5
9
```

Output:

```
20
220
1140

**ERROR:**
Wrong Answer. !!!Wrong Answer
```

Possibly your code doesn't work correctly for multiple test-cases (TCs).

The first test case where your code failed:

Input:

```
7786
```

Its Correct output is:

```
629456320324
```

And Your Code's output is:

```
-1903872188
```

Comment: The value is too big to fit in an `int`. Use a `long` or something bigger.

Comment: Using `long long` guarantees at least 64-bit numbers.  Using `long` may only give 32-bit numbers (e.g. on Windows 64).

Comment: If `n` is `7786`, then the maximum value of `i` is `1572`.  The code computes `i*i` which is `242487184`.  That just fits in a 32-bit integral type, but your code adds several values of similar magnitude, so overflows, and the behaviour is then undefined.  `int` is not guaranteed to represent values more than `32767`.   `long` is not guaranteed to represent more than `2147483647` (corresponding to a 32-bit integer).   So you need a variable that is larger than a `long`, such as a `long long`.

Answer (score 0):

Your data type for `s` is not big enough. You can specify that you would like a 64 bit int (which should be big enough):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n = 7786;
    uint64_t s = 0; // note the type

    for(int i = 1; i <= n*2; ++i)
    {
       if(i%2 == 0)
          s += i*i;
    }
    std::cout << s << std::endl;  // prints 629456320324
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4ywtg5).

Answer (score 0):

Use for the sum a more larger unsigned integer type (there is no sense to use a signed integer type) and just write a separate function that calculates the sum.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be written.

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned long long even_square_sum( unsigned int n )
{
    unsigned long long sum = 0;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        unsigned long long int even = 2 * ( i + 1 );
        sum += even * even;
    }

    return sum;
}

int main() 
{
    unsigned int n = 2;

    std::cout << n << ": " << even_square_sum( n ) << '\n';

    n = 5;

    std::cout << n << ": " << even_square_sum( n ) << '\n';

    n = 9;

    std::cout << n << ": " << even_square_sum( n ) << '\n';

    n = 7786;

    std::cout << n << ": " << even_square_sum( n ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2: 20
5: 220
9: 1140
7786: 629456320324
```

Pay attention to that there is also no sense to use a loop with the condition like

```
for(int i=1;i<=n*2;i++)
            ^^^^^^
```

because there are numerous redundant iterations of the loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    //code
    long int t,n,s;//Using long int removed the error
    cin>>t;//no. of test cases

    for(int k=1;k<=t;k++)
    {   cin>>n;s=0;

            for(int i=1;i<=n*2;i++)
            {
                if(i%2!=0)
                   s=s+(i*i);
            }
        cout<<s<<endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider including `<cstdint>` and using `int64_t` if it is available. That way you're guaranteed there will be no funny business. Right now the program is still vulnerable. `long int` is [only guaranteed to be no smaller than 32 bit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Properties), and 32 bit is not good enough.